# Python | Removing mirror pairs in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In python, I have an array of shape n*2 ( where n is a positive integer ). Essentially, this is an array of pairs. I wish to remove all *mirror pairs* in this array. For example, the following array **A**  is of shape **10*2**. The pairs **[0,55]** and **[55, 0]** would constitute one such *mirror pair* in A, and I wish to keep one out of those two.

```
A = np.array([[ 0, 55], [ 5, 25], [12, 62], [27,  32], [25, 73], 
              [55, 0], [25, 5], [62, 12], [32, 27], [99, 95]])
```

For the aforementioned example, I would want the result array to look like:

```
B = np.array([[ 0, 55], [ 5, 25], [12, 62], [27,  32], [25, 73], [99,95])
```

since there are 6 unique pairs (after 4 mirror pairs are excluded).

I realize that I can achieve this using two nested for loops, but I would want to achieve this using the **fastest possible method**, since for the actual problem at hand, I will be dealing with huge arrays. I will be thankful to have some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cryptic one-liner:

```
In [301]: A
Out[301]: 
array([[ 0, 55],
       [ 5, 25],
       [12, 62],
       [27, 32],
       [25, 73],
       [55,  0],
       [25,  5],
       [62, 12],
       [32, 27],
       [99, 95]])

In [302]: np.unique(np.sort(A, axis=1).view(','.join([A.dtype.char]*2))).view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, 2)
Out[302]: 
array([[ 0, 55],
       [ 5, 25],
       [12, 62],
       [25, 73],
       [27, 32],
       [95, 99]])
```

Break it down into steps...

First, create a copy that is sorted along the second axis.  In the sorted array, we want to remove duplicate rows.

```
In [303]: a = np.sort(A, axis=1)

In [304]: a
Out[304]: 
array([[ 0, 55],
       [ 5, 25],
       [12, 62],
       [27, 32],
       [25, 73],
       [ 0, 55],
       [ 5, 25],
       [12, 62],
       [27, 32],
       [95, 99]])
```

`numpy.unique()` can be used to find the unique elements of an array, but it only works with one-dimensional data.  So we'll create a one-dimensional view of `b` in which each row becomes a single structure with two fields.  One way to define the new data type that we want is as a string:

```
In [305]: dt = ','.join([A.dtype.char]*2)

In [306]: dt
Out[306]: 'l,l'
```

`b` is a structured array; it is the one-dimensional view of `a`:

```
In [307]: b = a.view(dt)

In [308]: b
Out[308]: 
array([[( 0, 55)],
       [( 5, 25)],
       [(12, 62)],
       [(27, 32)],
       [(25, 73)],
       [( 0, 55)],
       [( 5, 25)],
       [(12, 62)],
       [(27, 32)],
       [(95, 99)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

Now we use `numpy.unique()` to find the unique elements of `b`:

```
In [309]: u = np.unique(b)

In [310]: u
Out[310]: 
array([( 0, 55), ( 5, 25), (12, 62), (25, 73), (27, 32), (95, 99)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

Next, create a view of `u`, using the data type of the original array `A`.  This will be one-dimensional:

```
In [311]: v = u.view(A.dtype)

In [312]: v
Out[312]: array([ 0, 55,  5, 25, 12, 62, 25, 73, 27, 32, 95, 99])
```

Finally, reshape `v` to restore the two-dimensional array:

```
In [313]: w = v.reshape(-1, 2)

In [314]: w
Out[314]: 
array([[ 0, 55],
       [ 5, 25],
       [12, 62],
       [25, 73],
       [27, 32],
       [95, 99]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a pure python list, try the following code.

```
>>> list(set([tuple(i) for i in map(sorted, b)]))
[(27, 32), (5, 25), (12, 62), (95, 99), (25, 73), (0, 55)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the order of the pairs doesn't matter (for example: [1,2] = [2,1]). If this is the case, you can flip all pairs so that the first number is always smaller than the second number.

```
[[1,2], [4,3], [1,7], [10,2]]
```

becomes

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [1,7], [2,10]]
```

Then you could sort all the pairs by the first, then second number:

```
[[1,2], [1,7], [2,10], [3,4]]
```

Finally, you could loop through the list and remove any duplicate pairs.
If you use an efficient sorting algorithm, like a mergesort, this entire process will have O(n*log(n)) work, which is much better than O(n^2) work (what you get with nested for loops.

Answer (score 1):

I will show u my way(because it has one my favourites tricks to convert 1D list to nD),even if there are probably easier ways:

```
A = [[ 0, 55], [ 5, 25], [12, 62], [27,  32], [25, 73], 
     [55, 0], [25, 5], [62, 12], [32, 27], [99, 95]]
B=[]

long = int(len(A)/2)

for i in range(long):
  if A[i][0] == A[i+long][1] and A[i][1] == A[i+long][0]:
     B.append(A[i][0])
     B.append(A[i][1])
  else:
     B.append(A[i][0])
     B.append(A[i][1])
     B.append(A[i+long][0])
     B.append(A[i+long][1])
#Now we created an 1D list and then we convert it to 2D!

B=[B[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(B),2)]
```